# Converting shape into polygons in R

Tags: r

How can I convert **shape to polygons** in R. There was such an option "shape2poly" a few years ago but now its removed. Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Questions focusing on *programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform* are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: That function was not in R itself, but in some package. googling indicates maybe `maptools`

Comment: in maptools it does`n exists either :( is there any other way to receive polygons ?

Comment: maptools has another function `readShapePoly` which seems to fit the description

Comment: Be careful about using our site as a fallback from SE (which has already blocked you from asking question): if you ask one more off-topic question, the system is likely to block you here, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still access the `shape2poly()` function with ":::" from the maptools package like this:

`maptools:::shape2poly()`

They removed it from the user namespace so you can't call it directly. You can look up a similar question  [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-March/007841.html)

Little explanation from [an old stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582136/r-what-do-you-call-the-and-operators-and-how-do-they-differ):

> ":::" calls `get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE)`,
>   searching for the object name in the Namespace environment of the
>   package, and returning the value of the internal variable name.
>
> -from the user "theforestecologist"

So you can recall intern namespace usages with three colons.

Comment: @mischa11 you saved my life :)) its working !

Comment: @Ola you can accept the answer under the vote question arrows on the left if i helped you. There is a little green accept mark [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also this question will be likely migrated to stackoverflow since this was a programming question.